# How to invoke no-arg anonymous function with no parentheses

Tags: scala

Take this code:

```
var x = 10
val y = () => x + 1
```

I then want to treat y as if its a variable that holds an Int and changes anytime x changes. Essentially I want to bind y to x.

Problem is, if I just type `y` then I get the result `res0: () => Int = <function0>`
I was under the impression that you could invoke 0-arity functions without any parens, but I am required to use `y()` to get the behavior I am trying to achieve.

Is there a better way to define the anonymous function or do I need to use a different approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you need to do it like that? Just do `def y = x + 1`

```
scala> var x = 1
x: Int = 1

scala> def y = x + 1
y: Int

scala> y
res0: Int = 2

scala> x = 3
x: Int = 3

scala> y
res1: Int = 4
```

**EDIT to address some comments:**

If you define `val y = () => x + 1`, you are defining y as a value that holds a function that takes no argument and returns an Int. To call the function that is held by this variable, you will need to call it with (), to tell the compiler that you don't want to pass the value, but to execute (evaluate) the function that is within it.

If you define `val y = x + 1`, you are defining a value (constant), that is assigned in the moment it is executed, you could postpone evaluation using lazy, but once it is assigned, it will not be evaluated again.

If you define `def y = x + 1`, you are defining a function that returns x+1, which is what you want.

Comment: ah this is the behavior I desired. I tried `val y = x + 1` but that didnt work because x + 1 is only evaluated at initalization. Didn't think to use def like this. So essentially y is a zero-arity method that evaluates x + 1 everytime it is invoked?

Answer (score 1):

You have not defined a 0-arity function. You have actually defined a `Unit => Int` function. That is why you can not invoke it like you would like to invoke it. I've rarely seen 0-arity functions outside the context of come contained function scope:

```
def something[V](value: Int)(f: => V) = 
  if(value %2 == 0) f 
  else throw new Exception("not even (and also not evaluated f)")
```

where it is used as a lazily deferred execution body.

**Edit**: I would use the other person's answer.

Comment: ah I confused the arity. So scala's type system treats paramless anonymous function's as really taking one parameter of type Unit?

Comment: @sunrize920 the way you defined it, it treats them as a `Unit => SomeType`. The way @viniciusmiana defined it, that is a 0-arity function (However, I would strongly recommend keeping the parens for side-effecting functions.)

Comment: Regarding the use of parenthesis, Scala coding conventions says that you should force the use os parenthesis when the function has side-effects. In our case, it does not. It just return x +1, but it does not change x.